# How to work with git worktree in PhpStorm and see the result in a browser?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, git-worktree

I have a simple project`/var/www/testy.local` with one file `index.php` that contains: `<?php echo 111;`.

Apache settings is pretty standard:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName testy.local
   DocumentRoot /var/www/testy.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Result: in a browser with URL `http://testy.local` I see the result: 111

---

Now

- I create two git branches: `git branch b1`, `git branch b2`
- I create two worktrees: `git worktree add worktree/b1 b1`, `git worktree add worktree/b2 b2`
- I make changes in every `index.php` of these worktrees

**Question 1:** now, how do I see the result of my changes in the browser? I made changes in wortree/b1 and I want to see it, to make sure that I did it right and nothing is broken.
Apache points at the root of app, not at the switched worktree.

**Question 2:** How do I work with worktrees in the *PhpStorm*? How to switch between worktrees to see changed files in the "Commit" tab? What should I do to see branch `b1` in "branches corner" and how do I commit to the branch currently pointed to by worktree?

**It doesn't suit me** to type manually in the terminal commands `cd worktree/b1`, `git commit` etc

[image]

Comment: This very much feels like an X/Y problem what is the actual problem you have ?

Comment: @DavidT but it **IS** the actual problem. I don't know how to see the result of changes in worktrees and how to work in phpstorm with them.... Don't you find that is the problem?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000134610-Support-for-git-worktree